# getPointAtLength DOM Exception, but not when d-path is assigned *without* namespace

Tags: svg, xml-namespaces

Executing: `path.getPointAtLength(0)`

Is there any logic why a `path` must be created **with** a NameSpace.
But the `d` attribute must be assigned **without** a NameSpace?

Is it all Browser safe, to **not use** `setAttributeNS` for all other attributes?

- FireFox error:

> DOMException: SVGGeometryElement.getPointAtLength: No path available for measuring

- Chrome error:

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'getPointAtLength' on 'SVGGeometryElement': The element's path is empty.

```js
const _NAMESPACE_ = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
function getPoint(label, path) {
  try {
    let l = path.getPointAtLength(0);
    console.log(label, l.x , l.y )
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(label, e.stack.split("\n")[0])
  }
}
// Works fine:
let P1 = document.createElementNS(_NAMESPACE_, "path");
P1.setAttribute('d', `M1 1`);
getPoint('P1', P1);

//Error: DOMException The elements's path is empty
let P2 = document.createElementNS(_NAMESPACE_, "path");
P2.setAttributeNS(_NAMESPACE_, 'd', `M2 2`);
getPoint('P2', P2);

//Error: getPointAtLength is not a function
let P3 = document.createElement("path");
P3.setAttributeNS(_NAMESPACE_, 'd', `M3 3`);
getPoint('P3', P3);

//Error: getPointAtLength is not a function
let P4 = document.createElement("path");
P4.setAttribute('d', `M4 4`);
getPoint('P4', P4);

//works: namespace = null
let P5 = document.createElementNS(_NAMESPACE_, "path");
P5.setAttributeNS( null , 'd', `M5 5`);
getPoint('P5', P5);
```

Comment: Because that makes the markup shorter and simpler per https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#defaulting *Default namespace declarations do not apply directly to attribute names; the interpretation of unprefixed attributes is determined by the element on which they appear.*

Comment: There are a few legacy attributes that have namespaces e.g xlink:href (replaced by href), xml:space (replaced by css white-space)

Comment: I would use `P2.setAttributeNS(null, 'd', `M2, 2`);`